# I created a updatesite.nsf from updatesite.ntf template and trying to import a feature

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I created a updatesite.nsf from updatesite.ntf template and trying to import a feature  and I get an error says "LS2J Error: Java constructor failed to execute in (#304)..." And  a long message. Notes and Domino are 12.0.02 both 64 bit...Need help in this . Why am I getting this error ?  Nothing in Activity logs either in the updatesite.nsf.

The developer tried to create a JAR and trying to import it the Feature into the updatesite,nsf database and it errors out as above. It should import as I am expecting.

Comment: Try with the OpenNTF update site template at https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Open%20Eclipse%20Update%20Site

Comment: Thanks Per Henrik, I did this both templates from Openntf.org. Both 9 and 8 templates. I do get the same error again. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you contact HCL customer support and raise a "problem case": https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm